# Best practice to passing context to callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a object that has few methods and I want to bind one of them as event handler, but it uses other methods from the same object. What is the best practice to preserve context in callback functions?
As I see from jQuery UI core for this purpose commonly used method $.proxy, to be honest I don't like this approach, it isn't very clear.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
var obj = {
   someMethod: function(){...},
   callback : function(){
       ...
       this.someMethod(); // or this.someMethod.call(...)
       ...
   },
};
// wrong
$.bind(elm, obj.callback);
// using $.proxy
$.bind(elm, $.proxy(obj.callback, obj));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are basically:

- `$.proxy` (as you've pointed out)
- JavaScript 1.8's [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
- A non-native implementation of `Function.bind` (like, for example, [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind))
- An inline anonymous function: `$.bind(elm, function() { obj.callback.apply(obj, arguments })`

None of these are definitely better or definitely worse than the others (except maybe inline anonymous functions, which are kind of verbose, and `Function.bind` and friends are a bit more general than `$.proxy`). More important is to pick one and be consistent.

Comment: The other way is to use closure, but then I should pick up another way to organize code than just the object.