# How do I access methods in the scope of an object created with an object factory in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a hard time wrapping my head around variable scope in JS. Is there a way of accessing instance variables of an object created with an object factory similar to the example below?

```
function Renderer(id, options) {
    var id = id;
    var options = options;

    return {
        render: function(selector) {
            $(selector).each(function(index) {
                this.renderOptions(); //This does not reference the Renderer, but the html element selected by jQuery.
            });
        },
        renderOptions: function() {
            console.log(this.options);
        }
    }
}

var myRenderer = new Renderer('test', [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]);
```

Comment: You want to access id and options from an instance of from inside the object?

Comment: Yes... preferably I would prefix every method and variable inside the object to make their scope more obvious.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595888/best-practice-to-passing-context-to-callback-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep a named reference to your object, as `this` gets redefined on every method call and is usually pointing to the wrong context inside callbacks:

```
var instance = {
    render: function(selector) {
        $(selector).each(function(index) {
            instance.renderOptions();
        });
    },
    ...
}
return instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified code

```
function Renderer(id, options) {
    var id = id;
    var options = options;

    return {
        render: function(selector) {
            var self = this;
            $(selector).each(function(index) {
                self.renderOptions();  // here this is a reference of dom element.
            });
        },
        renderOptions: function() {
            console.log(this.options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `var options...` is within the scope of `Renderer`, you can simply use `options` inside of the `renderOptions` function.

You'll also want to create a reference to `this`, as other posters mentioned.

```
function Renderer(id, options) {
    var id = id;
    var options = options;

    return {
        render: function(selector) {
            var self = this;
            $(selector).each(function(index) {
                self.renderOptions();
            });
        },
        renderOptions: function() {
            console.log(options);
        }
    }
}
```

And, if I'm reading the intent of this code correctly, you'll probably want to pass a reference to the element into the `renderOptions` function:

```
function Renderer(id, options) {
    var id = id;
    var options = options;

    return {
        render: function(selector) {
            var self = this;
            $(selector).each(function(index) {
                self.renderOptions(this);
            });
        },
        renderOptions: function(ele) {
            $(ele).css(options); // or whatever you plan to do.
        }
    }
}
```